# Calling ob_flush() and flush(), yet browser doesn't show any output until script finishes

Tags: php, output-buffering

Hi
Please View Below Code :

```
<?php
ob_start();

echo "Start ...<br />\n";
for( $i = 0 ; $i < 10 ; $i++ )
{
    echo "$i<br />\n";
    ob_flush(); 
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}
echo "End ...<br />\n";
?>
```

It's Incorrect ? i'm tested it but my output show when script is done, have any solution ?

Comment: Have you tested this in multiple browsers?  Removing `ob_start()` might be one piece of the puzzle, but you might also need to do something similar to what Jürgen suggested if it still doesn't work in IE.

Comment: Tested it on FireFox 4, IE9, IE8, IE8, IE6, Chrome . all of theme doesen't work

Comment: Hm, just a wild guess, but do you have mod_gzip active for the mime type of your script?

Comment: No, not set Content-Encoding header in page

Comment: Just want to make that sure: in your `php.ini` you've set `output_buffering = On`, and **not** to a value (e.g. `output_buffering = 4096`), `zlib.output_compression = Off` and no panel or `.htaccess` file does overwrite this values?

Comment: tested [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php#85382) with LAMP and firefox 4 IE8 Chrome, only work in IE8

Comment: @Jürgen Thelen : Checked, all of theme is ok . i'm wondering from this problem !

Comment: @hope_is_grim, i have'nt LAMP, but doesn't must difrent width LAMP and WAMP

Comment: @Davood Jafari: Sorry, now I'm running out of ideas.. :( EDIT: you don't have a proxy between client and server, haven't you?

Comment: @Davood Jafari: Another thing came to my mind: maybe your Apache is using modules that buffer output by themselves. You could try disabling Apache modules one by one to see if a specific module is causing the problem.

Comment: Really Thank you about Continuous. Testet it and inform you

Comment: @JürgenThelen gzipping is disabled

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I seem to have run into this problem too.

Comment: @om_deshpande unfortunately no :(

Answer (score 14):

Hey man I was also got stuck in this problem 
and finally got the correct solution
here it is for you

you have to add content type for your page 
you can do that by two ways
 1. using html  tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Ex.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Wp Migration</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
for($i=0;$i<70;$i++)
{
echo 'printing...<br>';
ob_flush();
flush();
sleep(3);
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

1. using php header function

   `<?php header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' ); ?>`

Ex.

```
<?php 
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
for($i=0;$i<70;$i++)
{
echo 'printing...<br>';
ob_flush();
flush();
sleep(3);
}
?>
```

All the best

Comment: So it seems the browser gets the content with or without the content type line, however if you don't have it, the browser simply changes the loading indicator to "receiving data" without displaying anything. Once you send the content type first, sending any amount of data and flushing will work =))) I confirmed the same behavior exists when running on Apache and IIS (regardless of output buffering settings) so it's definitely due to the browser's own requirements.

Comment: ob_flush(): Failed to flush buffer. No buffer to flush

Answer (score 6):

Some browsers need to receive at least 256 characters before they start to render. Have you already tried to stuff more output like:

```
echo str_repeat('&nbsp;', 50) . "$i<br />\n";
```

**EDIT**:

Under `Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8i PHP/5.2.9` I was able to reproduce the problem of the OP by setting

```
zlib.output_compression = On
```

Turning it off again by

```
zlib.output_compression = Off
```

made the script work as wanted.

Answer (score 4):

Try removing the call to `ob_start()` on your first line : there is no need for you to enable output buffering -- and it probably causes troubles, here.

I've tested your code :

- If `ob_start()` is called on the first line, I only see the output when the script finishes, after 10 seconds
- If I remove that call to `ob_start()`, then, I see one line of output every second, as soon as it's displayed on the standard output.

Comment: If you remove `ob_start()`, then you should remove all the `ob_` calls as well.

Comment: Not sure about that *(If I remove the call to `ob_flush()`, I only see the output after the 10 seconds delay)* ; maybe it's because `output_buffering` is enabled in my php.ini, though ;;; see what's written on http://fr.php.net/flush too

Comment: are you sure ? tested in browser ?

Comment: is possible give me link to view result ?

Comment: I tested on my local computer *(and the Apache I've got on it is not accessible from the Internet)* ;; anyway, I just copy-pasted your code, and commented the `ob_start()` call.

Comment: I Tested it on local ( WAMP5 ) and Apache Web Server, both return output after 10 second ! i even tested this code on 2 server, but problem still exist .

Answer (score 2):

Using Chrome, I found out that many more bytes are required to by-pass the browser's buffer. In my case 4096 bytes was fine:

```
echo str_repeat(' ', 4096);
```

Also, adding some HTML element at the beginning also seemed to be mandatory:

```
echo $content . '<br />';
```

Comment: Probably better example is here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php#54841

Answer (score 1):

On my system it appears that FF4 needs more than 256 bytes to start rendering what is arriving from the server side, then i resolved with this at the beginning:

```
while (@ob_end_flush());
echo(str_repeat(' ',1024));
// ...etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered that this was due to Apache's gzip compression being in use for my case.

To turn gzip off for the 'flushing' script only, I created a new `.htaccess` file in the directory where the continuous output script resides, with the following:

```
<IfModule mod_env.c>
    SetEnv no-gzip 1
</IfModule>
```

Flushing is working as expected again.

Answer (score 1):

For people using FCGI / fast cgi.

```
FcgidOutputBufferSize 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It is correct. Works fine for me from CLI running PHP 5.3.3. If it's not working for you, your PHP install may have output buffering disabled.

I would also suggest putting [ob_end_flush()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php) at the end of your script to close the output buffer.

Comment: In Command Line Interface Worked, But Browser ... ! and output buffering is enable on my server :(

Comment: i have ob_end_flush() in place

Answer (score 0):

One sneaky issue with IE8 and flush(); is that if you're "flushing" out rows in a table. IE will only display tables when they're complete. This was my issue, and changing containers from table rows to divs solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `.htaccess` file to disable gzip output

```
<IfModule mod_env.c>
    SetEnv no-gzip 1
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using laravel framework and buffering did not work but. This is solution :

```
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
ob_start();

ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();
for($i = 1;$i<= 5;$i++){
    echo $i;
    ob_flush();
    flush();

    sleep(3);
}
```

You have to use first ob_end_flush();

Answer (score 0):

This flow works with Laravel too

```
ob_implicit_flush(true);
echo "Processing ... "; // Or give out JSON output
ob_flush();
sleep(5); //A time-consuming synchronous process (SMTP mail, maybe?)
echo "Done";
```