# PHP ob_flush(); doesn't work in IE10

Tags: php, flush, internet-explorer-10

I'm having a problem with PHP `ob_flush();`

Seems like it does not work only in IE10.

gzip and caching are disabled on server, it's works everywhere except IE10.

If somebody has any idea how to solve this mystery i would be grateful! :)

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"?  What happens?

Comment: Define "it does not work".
Do you get a error?

Comment: Did you tested on IE10 released today ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770917/calling-ob-flush-and-flush-yet-browser-doesnt-show-any-output-until-script

Comment: php has nothing to do with the browser, you probaby have another error not related, like with JS or similar

Comment: @IesusSonesson php doesn't .. but headers have.

Comment: @RocketHazmat By it doesn't work i mean flushed content does not showing up in browser. Seems like browser caching all content before displaying it.

Comment: @MihaiIorga still has nothing to do with the overflow buffer hence it simply just holds the content of any print, it shouldn't make any difference which browser you are using. if the header is wrong it's wrong in every browser ^^

Comment: How big is your output? IIRC the IE does not start output before a certain amount of bytes (255?)

Comment: @fab Just tested it. You are right. For some reason i though that i give more than 255 byte to the browser. Apparently i didn't. Please post your answer so i can accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your output is less than 256 bytes, this might be the problem.

Quote from the [flush() documentation](http://php.net/flush):

> Some versions of Microsoft Internet Explorer will only start to display the page after they have received 256 bytes of output, so you may need to send extra whitespace before flushing to get those browsers to display the page.

Answer (score 1):

send `header("Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8;");`