# flush / ob_flush not working on remote server

Tags: php, html, linux, apache

**Please Read Before you mark as CLONE to this**

I am running xampp on my local machine and when testing by writing http://localhost/test.php I am getting the desired output i.e. printing 1 to 10 after each second. But as soon as I change it to my local IP http://10.70.52.75/test.php it loads for 10 seconds and gives output in one shot. I actually need this method to collect output from a PHP script which will be running for 10-15 minutes.

Alredy checked the php.ini for buffering as off.

```
apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1); //can comment this line

header('Content-Encoding: none');

header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );

for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
   echo $i.'<br>';
   flush();
   ob_flush();
   sleep(1);
}
```

Tried all the hacks available on stackoverflow

- [PHP Flush/ob_flush not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481235/php-flush-ob-flush-not-working)
- [Calling ob_flush() and flush(), yet browser doesn't show any output until script finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770917/calling-ob-flush-and-flush-yet-browser-doesnt-show-any-output-until-script)
  and much more but did not get the correct one. Please try to run the code on your Linux server or try on my setup

http://host-1-89.linuxzoo.net/test.php

ssh to this  machine with root@linuxzoo.net
Password is "secure"

Let me know any one succeed in any way

Comment: Strange. I've tried it on three machines now and I can't reproduce the issue. I do see the issue on the link you provided, though.

Comment: I am using the same code there too the similar thing can be seen if i use a use my own system ip instead of localhost on xampp

Comment: I can't explain when you're running it through your local machine, but the link you posted is using cloudflare-nginx? That sounds like it could be the reason there.

Comment: I have setup for you a machine http://host-1-89.linuxzoo.net/test.php is the url

if you want to ssh to the machine root@linuxzoo.net
"secure" is the password. Please have a look Thank you very much

Comment: I see the same on this setup as well.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Are you able to see any issue in the server?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't really have time to go in and look around on your server. =/

Comment: Ok thanks for your help